# can't connect to 127.0.0.1.:8000 django server using postman

Tags: django-rest-framework

I created API using django rest_framework. I have to test that API using postman but getting these error Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to http://127.0.0.1.8000/api/.

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1.8000/api/` since 8000 is a port and not part of the IP.

Comment: Thanks ALFa http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/  tried this still not work.